# Is normalizing this mysql DATE column overkill?

Tags: mysql, normalization, denormalization

I'm considering ignoring the rules of normalization to make a table easier to work with and I'm wondering if this will cause any significant issues or go against best practices for this sort of thing.

I'm storing data for month ranges and I'll have lots of duplicate values for the `month` column. It will store the month and year with a junk value of 1 for the day so I'll get a lot of `'2015-03-01'` then a lot of `'2015-04-01'` next month, etc...

Here are my two options I'm considering:

```
table `data`
------------
`id` INT
`data` VARCHAR
`month` DATE
```

or normalized, which would prevent those duplicates but feels tedious and like it's not actually helping me

```
table `data`
-------------
`id` INT
`data` VARCHAR
`month_id` INT

table `month`
-----------
`id` INT
`month` DATE
```

Are there any good guidelines to follow when considering denormalization like this?

Edit: Here's some sample data for my first scenario:

```
INSERT INTO data
(data, month)
VALUES
('sample1', '2014-11-01'),
('sample2', '2014-11-01'),
('sample3', '2014-11-01'),
('sample4', '2014-11-01'),
('sample5', '2014-12-01'),
('sample6', '2014-12-01'),
('sample7', '2014-12-01'),
('sample8', '2014-12-01'),
('sample9', '2014-12-01');
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of what is currently being stored with your current layout, preferable a SQLFiddle of it?

Comment: Nah, I don’t think you should do that (the 2nd one). When it comes to ordering the data by date, or searching records for a certain time period, you want to be able to use an index on your date column directly – having to translate that through another table first would be less effective. And besides, a date qualifies as an atomic value IMHO.

Comment: sqlfiddle is down for me right now but I've amended my question with an insert statement for the first scenario.

Comment: This has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: @SyntaxError Does your `data` column have anything that would be better split into another column with its own datatype? Is it a whole file of a report or something like that, could you provide a bit more info on it? Your first table at the top seems to me, more of a common way for this, the duplicates aren't really a issue here AFAIK unless there is or could be some peculiarities to what your `data` is or hold.

Comment: @Prix It's monthly stats numbers but I'm showing a stripped down version to avoid getting sidetracked on things that aren't central to my question.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I see that you're a database guy and although I'm not I am confused why you think data redundancy has nothing to do with normalization. Unfortunately I'm not willing to play 20 questions to find out so you're welcome to ignore my post and find one more worthy.

Comment: You're replacing repeated months with repeated id numbers; that alone won't change the normal form of a relation. There's no such thing as "replace text with id numbers" normal form. Replacing text with id numbers is a kind of data compression, not a kind of normalization.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Thank you, that kind of info is exactly what I'm here for and that makes sense. Do you mind posting that as an answer? Also is the only benefit of that to save space, and would that be a very small benefit unless the table has a really large number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

If, in your second option, table month only contains id and month, I would have to say "what's the point of that?".  If it contained extra information about month, (eg. number of working days in the month) it will be worth normalising it out.

Comment: I agree with your point about considering if we're storing any meta data for the month.The only point I can think of is preventing a large number of duplicate values. Duplicate values freak me out and make me feel like I'm doing things wrong. It would save a (probably negligible) amount of space as well but I suspect it is actually less efficient performance-wise.

Comment: If performance is your top priority I think you would need to do benchmarks to be sure you have the right approach.  If you need some sort of future-proofing where the month table might, in future, contain extra info it would be worth having two tables.  If simplicity is the key, one table seems sufficient to me.